# Assertions not satisfied while mocking a route's endpoins, which end up calling the real ones

Tags: testing, mocking, apache-camel, endpoint

I have defined the following route:

```java
from(direct(Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER))
    .routeId(Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER)
    // Split the usernames on an individual exchange each. This property is a Set<String>.
    .split(simpleF("${exchangeProperty.%s}", ExchangeProperty.USERNAMES))
        // Set the flag for the next route's processor.
        .setProperty(ExchangeProperty.SINGLE_EMAIL_PER_USER, constant(true))
        .to(direct(Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP))
    .end();
```

And written the following test:

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class EmailRouteBuilderTest extends CamelQuarkusTestSupport {
    @Inject
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Override
    public String isMockEndpoints() {
        return "*";
    }

    @Test
    void testIndividualEmailPerUser() throws InterruptedException {
        final Set<String> usernames = Set.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

        final Exchange exchange = this.createExchangeWithBody("");
        exchange.setProperty(ExchangeProperty.USERNAMES, usernames);

        final MockEndpoint sendEmailBopEndpoint = this.getMockEndpoint(String.format("mock:direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP), false);
        sendEmailBopEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(5);

        this.producerTemplate.send(String.format("direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER), exchange);

        sendEmailBopEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

However, when I run the test, I see all sorts of error messages from the `Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP` route, which attempts to contact the real service, and the assertion fails with "expected 5 messages, 0 received". The logs indicate the following:

```
2023-08-31 09:51:55,896 INFO  [org.apa.cam.com.moc.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy] (main) Adviced endpoint [direct://send-email-single-per-user] with mock endpoint [mock:direct:send-email-single-per-user]
2023-08-31 09:51:55,897 INFO  [org.apa.cam.com.moc.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy] (main) Adviced endpoint [direct://send-email-bop] with mock endpoint [mock:direct:send-email-bop]
2023-08-31 09:51:55,896 INFO  [org.apa.cam.com.moc.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy] (main) Adviced endpoint [http://boplocalhost:9999] with mock endpoint [mock:http:boplocalhost:9999]
```

The last line of the log corresponds to the service. I think I am understanding this whole thing wrong: I thought that mocking the endpoints made Camel not call the real services or the subsequent routes.

I have tried replacing `isMockEndpoints` with `isMockEndpointsAndSkip` but then the test doesn't work as well.

May you please help me understanding what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

**EDIT:** Updated code with "adviceWith":

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class EmailRouteBuilderTest extends CamelQuarkusTestSupport {
    @Inject
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    void testIndividualEmailPerUser() throws Exception {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(this.context, Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP, a -> {
            a.mockEndpointsAndSkip("*");
        });

        final Set<String> usernames = Set.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

        final Exchange exchange = this.createExchangeWithBody("");
        exchange.setProperty(ExchangeProperty.USERNAMES, usernames);

        final MockEndpoint sendEmailBopEndpoint = this.getMockEndpoint(String.format("mock:direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP), false);
        sendEmailBopEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(5);

        this.producerTemplate.send(String.format("direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER), exchange);

        sendEmailBopEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

This generates the following error message:

```
2023-09-04 10:11:34,767 WARN  [org.apa.cam.sup.EventHelper] (main) Error notifying event 85D6EC0051F6FCF-0000000000000000 exchange completed took: 5ms. This exception will be ignored.: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.camel.Endpoint.getEndpointUri()" because "endpoint" is null
```

And makes the test fail as well:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://direct:send-email-bop Received message count. Expected: <5> but was: <0>
Expected :<5>
Actual   :<0>
```

---

Thanks to Vignesh's comment, I was able to make it work. Notice the route specification in the `AdviceWith.adviceWith`:

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class EmailRouteBuilderTest extends CamelQuarkusTestSupport {
    @Inject
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    void testIndividualEmailPerUser() throws Exception {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(this.context, Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER, a -> {
            a.mockEndpointsAndSkip(String.format("direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP));
        });

        final Set<String> usernames = Set.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

        final Exchange exchange = this.createExchangeWithBody("");
        exchange.setProperty(ExchangeProperty.USERNAMES, usernames);

        final MockEndpoint sendEmailBopEndpoint = this.getMockEndpoint(String.format("mock:direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP), false);
        sendEmailBopEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(5);

        this.producerTemplate.send(String.format("direct:%s", Routes.SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER), exchange);

        sendEmailBopEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Initially, I was trying to mock and skip a different route from the one I was testing. With this last change, I'm saying "from this route I'm testing, mock this particular endpoint", which apparently makes Apache mock the endpoint I want.

That makes the test pass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the comment as answer.

"*" indicates to mock all routes. Specific route should be mocked instead.
Ex: "direct:send_email_bop"

Answer (score 1):

Mocking an endpoint essentially causes the endpoint to be instrumented so that a test can assert things about the endpoint, e.g. how many messages it received. However, the endpoint being mocked still gets executed. Mock-and-skip takes the additional step of preventing the original endpoint from being executed.

It's not clear what you mean by mock-and-skip causes your test to not work well. If you need the mock to return a stub value, look into [MockEndpoint.whenAnyExchangeReceived()](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-mock/latest/org/apache/camel/component/mock/MockEndpoint.html#whenAnyExchangeReceived(org.apache.camel.Processor)).

Comment: What I meant was that when I try to "mockAndSkip" with `AdviceWith` for the endpoint at the end of the route I'm testing —see the updated code—, I don't get the 5 messages I am expecting.

Comment: @MikelAlejoBR can you try providing specific route to skip instead of "*" like "direct:send_mail_bop"

Comment: Thank you so much Vignesh! By changing the adviced route to the one I was actually testing the test passed. Since I was testing `SEND_EMAIL_BOP_SINGLE_PER_USER`, I had to advice that one and mock the `SEND_EMAIL_BOP` endpoint from that route. My initial try was to mock `SEND_EMAIL_BOP` directly, but since "it's not connected to the former and was independent", that didn't work. I've left the code solution in my question. If you post an answer I'll accept it. Thank you both for giving me a hand with this!